# How to use fitcnb (Naive Bayes) in Matlab with discrete attributes?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, naivebayes

I have a data set as shown below:

[image]

First and second attributes (Refund, Marital Status) is **discrete attributes**.
Third attribute (Taxable income) is **continues attribute**.

i want to build a model in matlab and train it on this table.

Here is my try:

[image]

and i got this error message:

> A normal distribution cannot be fit for the combination of class Yes and predictor x1. The data has zero variance.

any one can help or guide me to how use **fitcnb** properly in matlab ?

Comment: Please copy the code from matlab editor and post it, the screenshot can't be reproduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to specify the Categorical or discrete attributes to the fitcnb

> Mdl = fitcnb(Data,Classes,'CategoricalPredictors',[1 2]);